# Select Into error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt.virtuemart_product_id,   
xfqti_virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_media_id 
INTO #tempTable 
FROM xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt
```

Gives syntax error, I'm about to pull my hair off

Comment: I'm very sure the database engine isn't just giving you "sintax error".  What is the actual error message you're getting?  And what database system are you using?

Comment: where is this `xfqti_virtuemart_product_medias` coming from?

Comment: Error 1064 near From

Comment: @vkp Even with only one field it gives error

Comment: tag the question with the dbms being used

Comment: SELECT 
virtuemart_product_id
INTO #tempTable 
FROM xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt  = Error 1064

Comment: Is `SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt` return some data ?

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes, it returns data

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into and Selecthave these sintax

```
  Insert into your_Table (col1,col2)
  SELECT 
  xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt.virtuemart_product_id,   
 xfqti_virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_media_id 

  FROM xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt
```

for create table

```
  Create  your_Table as 
  SELECT 
  xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt.virtuemart_product_id,   
 xfqti_virtuemart_product_medias.virtuemart_media_id 

  FROM xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt
```

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira   you must change the word  "your_table" with the proper code ... i don't know the name of your_table

Comment: The problem is that I want to create a table with the select, I dont wanna use one that already exists

Comment: Which bd model you are using ?

Comment: I dont know, its not my DB, I'm just trying to pull data to import to a new one. Basically I'm trying a list of result based on a ID. With that bunch of IDs I want to search another table in order to pull another field

Answer (score 0):

Being Virtuemart, I'm guessing this is a MySQL database. If so, the correct syntax for creating a temp table is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTableName AS
(
   SELECT field1, field2
   FROM yourtable;
)
```

That being said, your `SELECT` statement has two fields from two different tables, but only one of those tables is mentioned in the FROM clause of your statement. They should really both be in there and JOINed. Something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempTableName AS
(
   SELECT 
      t1.virtuemart_product_id,   
      t2.virtuemart_media_id 
   FROM 
      xfqti_virtuemart_products_pt_pt as t1 
      INNER JOIN xfqti_virtuemart_product_medias as t2 ON
          t1.product_id = t2.product_id
)
```

Or something.. I can't see your tables and it's been years since I used Virtuemart, so it's just a guess at the table relationship.